# Invoke make from different directory with python script

Tags: python, linux

I need to invoke make (build a makefile) in a directory different from the one I'm in, from inside a Python script. If I simply do:

```
build_ret = subprocess.Popen("../dir1/dir2/dir3/make",
                     shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

I get the following:
/bin/sh: ../dir1/dir2/dir3/make: No such file or directory

I've tried:

```
build_ret = subprocess.Popen("(cd ../dir1/dir2/dir3/; make)",
                     shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

but the make command is ignored. I don't even get the "Nothing to build for" message.

I've also tried using "communicate" but without success. This is running on Red Hat Linux.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd go with @Philipp's solution of using `cwd`, but as a side note you could also use the `-C` option to make:

```
make -C ../dir1/dir2/dir3/make
```

#### -C *dir*, --directory=*dir*

> Change to directory *dir* before reading the makefiles or doing anything else.  If multiple -C options are specified, each is interpreted relative to the previous one: `-C / -C etc` is equivalent to `-C /etc`. This is typically used with recursive invocations of make.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `cwd` argument, and use the list form of `Popen`:

```
subprocess.Popen(["make"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd="../dir1/dir2/dir3")
```

Invoking the shell is almost never required and is likely to cause problems because of the additional complexity involved.

Comment: The python docs say the following:
If cwd is not None, the child’s current directory will be changed to cwd before it is executed. Note that this directory is not considered when searching the executable, so you can’t specify the program’s path relative to cwd.

So I'm not sure if that will work.

Comment: The `make` program should be in the search path, of course. I'm pretty sure that this works (unless I made some silly typo) because I'm using it all the time.

Comment: Of course, in this case this is correct. I got a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the full path, you can get the location of the python script by calling

```
sys.argv[0]
```

to just get the path:

```
os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
```

You'll find quite some path manipulations in the [os.path module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html)

Comment: Be careful when just using `os.path.dirname`. It returns an empty string when given just a file name. Calling `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))` will always get you the the full path.